# How to transfer relation from one table to another with new ID in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, relation

I have table: `T1 (ID BIGINT, NAME NVARCHAR(1000))`

Data:

```
select * from T1
1, AAA
2, BBB
3, CCC
4, DDD
```

The `RELATIONS_T` (`ID, T1_ID1,T1_ ID2`) table holds relationships between `ID`’s from `T1` table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM RELATIONS_T
```

Output:

```
ID, T1_ID1,T1_ ID2
1,    1,   2
```

In this table 1 is connected to 2

The `RELATIONS_LOG_TABLE` (`ID, OLD_ID, NEW_ID, OLD_STUFF_ID, NEW_STUFF_ID`) has columns `OLD_STUFF_ID` and `NEW_STUFF_ID` that are not important for my question.

```
Select ID, OLD_ID, NEW_ID 
from RELATIONS_LOG_TABLE
```

Output:

```
ID, OLD_ID, NEW_ID
1, 1, 3
2, 2, 4
```

This means that 1 becomes 3, and 2 becomes 4

How can I check from table RELATIONS_LOG_TABLE and RELATIONS_T that there is connections between 1 and 2, and manually enter in table RELATIONS_T      3,   4.

Comment: So the change from id 1 to id 3 means "don't look at record #1 anymore, it has been replaced with record #3"? But record #3 could have been replaced by record #5 by now and so on, right? So one would have to look iteratively (recursively) for the last replacement. Is this correct?

Comment: 1 become invalid, 3 is then valid, but I have to check in table RELATIONS_T for relations for 1 and if exists then create relations for 3.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can there be a record OLD_ID=3 NEW_ID=5 in RELATIONS_LOG_TABLE, so that 1 was replaced by 3, but 3 was replaced by 5? If so, what to do then?

Comment: Yes, it can be, 3 can be replaced with 5.
But my problem is to replicate same relations in table RELATIONS_T, meaning that 1 is connected to 2.
In table RELATIONS_T I need to see 3, 4 because there was 1,2 and 1 has become 3, and 2 become 4.

Comment: Okay that looks easy. I feared you wanted to see 5,4 rather than 3,4. I will think of a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement would insert the tuples

```
3,2 (1 replaced by 3)
1,4 (2 replaced by 4)
3,4 (both replaced)
```

```
insert into relations_t (id1, id2)
  select coalesce(rep1.new_id, id1), coalesce(rep2.new_id, id2)
  from relations_t r
  left join relations_log_table rep1 on rep1.old_id = r.id1
  left join relations_log_table rep2 on rep2.old_id = r.id2
  where rep1.id is not null or rep2.id is not null;
```

If you only want the "best" record (both replaced if this is the case, else one replaced), you must get the top record according to number of replacements.

```
insert into relations_t (id1, id2)
  select top(1) coalesce(rep1.new_id, id1), coalesce(rep2.new_id, id2)
  from relations_t r
  left join relations_log_table rep1 on rep1.old_id = r.id1
  left join relations_log_table rep2 on rep2.old_id = r.id2
  where rep1.id is not null or rep2.id is not null
  order by case when rep1.id is not null and rep2.id is not null then 0 else 1 end;
```